# Azure Databricks pyspark readstream reads non orc files from the mounted ADLS Gen2 input path

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake

I am using Databricks pyspark readstream and write stream like below.

I am reading the orc file from the mounted ADLS Gen2 Azure store, Below is the fragment of the code, where the files is read from a location.

Say, input data is loaded by a process

```
my-storage-account/my-container/table1/input/
             |
              - loadDate_20220621/
             |          |- file1.orc
             |          |- file2.orc
             |_ sample.json
             |_ file.json
```

```py
domains = [ 'table1','table2']

for domain in domains:
   with open('{}/{}.json'.format(mount_path, schema_name), 'r') as jfile:
      table_schema = T.StructType.fromJson(json.loads(jfile.read()))
   )
   data_schema[domain] = table_schema

for domain in domains:
  #read stream 
  data_readstream = ( 
    spark.readStream
    .format("orc")    # READING ORC FORMAT
    .schema(data_schema[domain])
    .load(f'{mount_path}/input/data/')
  )

## other operattion to perform merge data
## create merge upsert function and store in the list

 def mergeTbl1(df, batch_id): 
  data_df = (
    df
    .dropDuplicates(['field1'])
  ) 
  data_df.createOrReplaceTempView("table1_temp")
 
  data_df._jdf.sparkSession().sql("""
    MERGE INTO my_db.table1 tbl1
    USING table1_temp tbl1u
    ON tbl1.field1 = tbl1u.field1
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET *
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT *                     
    """)

def mergeTbl2(df, batch_id): 
  data_df = (
    df
    .dropDuplicates(['field2'])
  ) 
  data_df.createOrReplaceTempView("table1_temp")
 
  data_df._jdf.sparkSession().sql("""
    MERGE INTO my_db.table2 tbl2
    USING table2_temp tbl2u
    ON tbl2.field2 = tbl2u.field2
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET *
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT *                     
    """)

mergeUpsertFunctionList['table1] = mergeTbl1
mergeUpsertFunctionList['table2] = mergeTbl2


for domain in domains:
  # write stream
  data_writestream = ( 
    data_readstreams[domain]
    .repartition(1)
    .writeStream
    .trigger(once=True)
    .format("delta")
    .option("checkpointLocation", f"{mount_path}/checkpoints/{domain}")
    .foreachBatch(mergeUpsertFunctionList[domain])
    .start()
  )
```

Below is the exception i get, which is strange since with ORC format in readstream, expect spark to read only ORC formats not json,

Question:

- This is new since i do have other notebook job which works fine. Sometimes those json file is locked by lease by another process but that shouldn't impact the ORC files.

Any reason why this is happening?

```
 File "/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 2442, in _call_proxy
    return_value = getattr(self.pool[obj_id], method)(*params)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 202, in call
    raise e
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 199, in call
    self.func(DataFrame(jdf, self.sql_ctx), batch_id)
  File "<command-313423169960053>", line 15, in mergeDataTable1
    df
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 740, in save
    self._jwrite.save(path)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1304, in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 117, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
    raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o855.save.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.jobAbortedError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:606)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:360)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$$nestedInanonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1(QueryExecution.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$8(SQLExecution.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:360)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1(SQLExecution.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:968)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$$nestedInanonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$$nestedInanonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:575)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:167)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:575)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:268)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:551)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1(QueryExecution.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.eagerlyExecuteCommands(QueryExecution.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertCommandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:959)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:427)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:396)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:250)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:380)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:295)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 10) (10.44.216.76 executor 0): com.databricks.sql.io.FileReadException: Error while reading file dbfs:/mnt_path/input............../file.json.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1$$anon$2.logFileNameAndThrow(FileScanRDD.scala:521)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1$$anon$2.getNext(FileScanRDD.scala:494)
    at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:614)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.$anonfun$hasNext$1(FileScanRDD.scala:356)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcZ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcZ$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:351)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FileSourceScanExec$$anon$1.hasNext(DataSourceScanExec.scala:1017)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.columnartorow_nextBatch_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:759)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:759)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:140)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.$anonfun$runTask$3(ShuffleMapTask.scala:81)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.$anonfun$runTask$1(ShuffleMapTask.scala:81)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.$anonfun$run$1(Task.scala:125)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$13(Executor.scala:826)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1681)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:829)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:684)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.orc.FileFormatException: Malformed ORC file dbfs:/mount_path/input....../.../sample.json. Invalid postscript.
    at org.apache.orc.impl.ReaderImpl.ensureOrcFooter(ReaderImpl.java:462)
    at org.apache.orc.impl.ReaderImpl.extractFileTail(ReaderImpl.java:795)
    at org.apache.orc.impl.ReaderImpl.<init>(ReaderImpl.java:564)
    at org.apache.orc.OrcFile.createReader(OrcFile.java:385)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcFileFormat.$anonfun$buildReaderWithPartitionValues$2(OrcFileFormat.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithResource(Utils.scala:3035)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcFileFormat.$anonfun$buildReaderWithPartitionValues$1(OrcFileFormat.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1$$anon$2.getNext(FileScanRDD.scala:457)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few approaches here:

- You can use [path filter](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-generic-options.html#path-global-filter) to select only `.orc` files:

```py
data_readstream = ( 
    spark.readStream
    .format("orc")    # READING ORC FORMAT
    .schema(data_schema[domain])
    .option("pathGlobFilter", "*.orc")
    .load(f'{mount_path}/input/data/')
  )
```

- Ignore files considered corrupted using the `spark.sql.files.ignoreCorruptFiles` Spark configuration ([doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-generic-options.html#ignore-corrupt-files)), althought this is not an optimal solution.

Comment: Adding the option worked, I will not be using the option to enable the configuration `spark.sql.files.ignoreCorruptFiles`, good to know on this option.